# How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I use [Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) to store all articles I need and bibtex4word add-on (in MS Word) to maintain the reference list. So, I would like to know how to properly fill the "author" field in Jabref with multiple authors to appear them correct in the reference list.

For example, I've got the article with several authors:

> E. Orti, J.L. Bredas, C. Clarisse

And I would like them to appear in this manner. But instead I get this:

> C. C. E. Orti, J. L. Bredas

Comment: With your setup, the `author` field is interpreted as containing a single author, with "E. Orti" as the surname component, "J.L. Bredas" as the junior component, and "C. Clarisse" as the first-name component. The bibliography style you employ appears to be set to (a) abbreviate first names down to their initials and (b) place the first-name initials *before* the surname component. Moreover, the junior component is separated from the remainder of the name with a comma. That's why you're getting "C. C. E. Orti, J.L. Bredas" as the formatted output. Moral of the story: Use proper input syntax.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

The appropriate separator for authors is "and". Comma is used to distinguish first and last name ([link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Authors)):

```
author = "Orti, E. and Bredas, J.L. and Clarisse, C.",
```

Comment: Just a comment for people looking at this later. Biber 1.5+ allows you to customise the separator for names and lists to something other than 'and' if you want to.

Comment: @stefan, Here is the page on archive.org (from June 20, 2013): https://web.archive.org/web/20130620150431/http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html

Comment: Shouldn't `J.L.` be `J. L.`?

Comment: Better yet is J.~L. this way there is a space between the two initials but the 5 characters (2 letter, 2 full stops, and one space) are treated as on typographical unit and will always appear on the same line.

Comment: We should avoid using `\&` or any other separators, am I right?

Comment: @PLK Isn't that just for how it's displayed, not parsed?

Comment: @Noldorin - no, the biber options are for parsing - there are biblatex macros for changing display

Comment: @PLK, Yes, it's the `--namesep` operator, for anyone wondering.