# Citing multiple authors with alternate separator than "and" using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I'm using LyX on Linux Mint 14 ...

Using BibTeX with the `apalike` style and some modifications in the preamble, I've managed to get the bibliography as it should be except for one thing. When I cite a work with multiple authors it gets printed with the separator "and" which isn't correct for my language (Danish). Curiously it's displayed correctly in the user interface of Lyx - for example "(Wittgenstein og Waismann 2003 - which led me to believe everything was ok but in the pdf the separator "and" is used both in the reference and in the bibliography.

Is there any way to fix this using BibTeX, or can it only be done with biber 1.5, as suggested in the last comment here: [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file)

I really hope their is because getting biber to work using the following guide has thus far proven to be impossible: http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Help much appreciated ... I really hope I won't have to relapse into setting my master thesis up in LibreOffice.

Comment: Do you mean in the output or in the `.bib` file? The latter _has_ to use `and`, but this should not affect the PDF output if you use a suitable BibTeX style. The `apalike` style is not going to work for you here, so you may well be best getting `biblatex` working.

Comment: @JosephWright - I'm curious to find out what you mean by "The `apalike` style is not going to work for you...". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Mico The `apalike` style does not include any `babel` or similar hooks, so at least without editing a copy of the style (not really what Lyx is about) it's not possible to change the output language of the fixed phrases.

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks for this. Indeed, the `apalike` style is rather old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answer and the comments! I just found this package with a Danish version of the standard styles including apalike: http://www.tug.dk/projekter/dk-bib so this will be my solution.

For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: the styles are included in the package texlive-bibtex-extra along with similarly translated styles - so this might also be the solution for problems like this in other languages.

Thanks again for the great reply though - I already like TeX and the community a lot ...

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you want to stick with the `apalike` bibliography style, you'll need to edit it a wee bit, as follows:

- Locate the file `apalike.bst` on your system, and copy it to a new file called, say, `ogapalike.bst`. Don't edit the original file directly.
- Open the file `ogapalike.bst` in your favorite editor.
- Locate the following line in the function `format.names` (it's on l. 225 in my copy of this file):

  ```
                { " and " * t * }
  ```

  and change it -- you guessed it -- to

  ```
                { " og " * t * }
  ```
- Locate the following line in the function `format.lab.names` (it's on l. 851 in my copy of the file):

  ```
              { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```

  and change it -- you guessed right again! -- to

  ```
              { " og " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```
- Save the file `ogapalike.bst` either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located, or somewhere in the search path of your TeX distribution; if you do the latter, be sure to update the TeX filename database according to the distribution's suggestions. Start using it with the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{ogapalike}
  ```

  The first time you use the new style file, be sure to rerun BibTeX and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all "and to og" changes...

Happy (Bib)TeXing!