# Change separator of multiple authors in references using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I am working on my master thesis and I have problem with citing multiple authors. The separator in pdf is "and", but this is not correct in my language. Is there a **simple** solution to change this separator?

Thanks for every answer

here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
  blba bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{x}

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

It produces results like:
[image: the "and" shouldn't be there]

Comment: Biblatex has localisation files for strings and knows about babel. They're written in your_language.lbx.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You’ll find tips for a `biblatex` MWE in my answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but that is unfortunately not a MWE. A MWE should contain all (and only) the code that’s needed to produce e.g. what your picture shows.

Comment: @Truthseeker Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104128/citing-multiple-authors-with-alternate-separator-than-and-using-bibtex? The 'copy and edit the `.bst` file' method there is generally true for non-`biblatex` styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, from the command line, run

> kpsewhich plain.bst

to know where the file `plain.bst` is. Its path should be `TEXMF/bibtex/bst/base/`.

Now copy `plain.bst` in the directory where your `.tex` file is, and rename it to `myplain.bst`.

Then open `myplain.bst` in your editor and search for the lines:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Replace them with the following

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

and save the file.

Now in your document, replace

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{myplain}
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{x,
author = {Author, A and Buthor, B and Cuthor, C},
journal = {A journal},
title = {A title},
year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
  blba bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{x}

  \bibliographystyle{myplain}
  \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `biblatex`, take a look on the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), section **3.9.1 Generic Commands and Hooks**.

`\finalnamedelim` is probably the bibliography string you want to change. You can do that easily with:

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
```

You may also take a look at the `\multinamedelim`-string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is that I have to use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. Do you know similar solution for this package too?