# Is it possible to translate the 'and' separator in references using BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using the standard *plain* style for my bibliography. My document is written in Dutch, so I'm using the `babel` package, but the *and* separator before the last author isn't translated to the Dutch alternative *en*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

After reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232154/38587), I know how to create a custom style *myplain*, where *and* is changed to *en*, but I was wondering whether it is truly necessary to create a new style for this.

Aren't `babel` and some other trick sufficient? If not, does one have to create a new style for every language (e.g. in French, *and* is *et*)?

Comment: 'No': the plain style has `and` as a literal hard-coded.

Comment: use a Harvard compatible style. Then you can redefine `\harvardand`

Comment: @Herbert - The bibliography styles provided by the [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) package are meant to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. We don't know, though, if the OP wishes to generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I need numeric-style citation call-outs... :)

Comment: Here is a `deplain.bst` which uses `und` http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/BibTeX/. It is easy to modify it for any other language

Comment: This would be automatic with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `babelbib`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ur,
  author={A. Uthor and W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2016},
}
@book{x,
  editor={E. Ditor},
  title={Collection},
  year={2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{ur}, \cite{x}

\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to modify the `plain` bibliography style file, I would actually recommend that you modify the `plainnat` style instead, for two reasons. First, compared with the `plain` style, `plainnat` is about 20 years younger and thus knows what to do with fields such as `url`, `doi`, `eid`, `isbn`, and `issn`. Second, when used with the `natbib` citation management package, it's trivially easy with `plainnat` to switch back and forth between numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs, should the need to do so ever arise; in contrast, `plain` can only generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

Here's what you could do:

- Locate the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. (If you have TeXLive 2015, you may find it at `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/natbib/plainnat.bst`.)
- Make a copy of the file, calling the copy, say, `plainnat-nl.bst`. Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.
- Open `plainnat-nl.bst` in your favorite text editor -- the editor you use for your tex files will do fine -- and replace all three instances of `" and "` with `" en "`. (In my copy of the file, these instances occur on lines 232, 325, and 1111.)
- Save the file `plainnat-nl.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you use TeXLive, try running `sudo texhash`.)
- Change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` to `plainnat-nl`, load the `natbib` package with the options `square` and `numbers`, and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!