# How to set the english option to abntex2cite bibliography package?

Tags: bibliographies, abnt

Running this minimal example:

```
% How to make \PassOptionsToPackage add the option as the last option?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385895/how-to-make
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english}{babel}
\documentclass{abntex2}

% Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384885/package
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

% Is it possible to translate the 'and' separator in references using BibTeX?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305975/is-it-possible
\usepackage{babelbib}

% Citação alfabética por autor-data [alf]
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

% How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104159/how-does-filecontents-keep-latex
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc{koma-scrguien,
  author = "Markus Kohm",
  edition = "2017-04-13",
  howpublished = "\url{http://mirrors.ibiblio.org//doc/scrguien.pdf}",
  publisher = "Online Material; \url{https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script}",
  title = "The Guide KOMA -Script",
  urlaccessdate = "28 ago 2017",
  note         = "[Online; Accessed 2017-08-28]",
  year = "2017"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    Citing \cite{koma-scrguien}

    \bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

We still got portuguese text on the bibliography:

[image]

Looking over the implementation on:

1. https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/8f2109ac2ef986b15d97d0bfc489b251918f1761/bibtex/bst/abntex2/abntex2-alf.bst#L291-L296

   ```
   FUNCTION {bbl.url.accessdate}
     {iso.abbreviation { "Cited "} {"Acesso em: "} if$}
   FUNCTION {bbl.url.available}
   { iso.abbreviation {"Available from Internet: "} {"Dispon{\'\i}vel em: "} if$}
   FUNCTION {bbl.void} {""}
   FUNCTION {bbl.volume} { iso.abbreviation {"vol."} {"v."} if$ }
   ```

We see they have both english and portuguese versions of the `Dispon{\'\i}vel em:` and `Available from Internet:`

Is it possible to switch between them? Or is there some way to replace portuguese text with an english one as I do with the `backref`:

```
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Cited on page(s):~}
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]
{
    \ifcase #1
        No citation in the text.
    \or
        Cited on page #2.
    \else
        Cited #1 times on pages #2.
    \fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `.bst` name, and change the Portuguese parts in:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.url.accessdate}
  {iso.abbreviation { "Cited "} {"Acesso em: "} if$}
FUNCTION {bbl.url.available}
{ iso.abbreviation {"Available from Internet: "} {"Dispon{\'\i}vel em: "} if$}
FUNCTION {bbl.void} {""}
FUNCTION {bbl.volume} { iso.abbreviation {"vol."} {"v."} if$ }
```

to the ones you'd like to appear, then use the new style file.

Or better: **use the [biblatex-abnt](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt) package** and worry no more.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to my latex document. I had to specify two languages, the first was Brazil Portuguese and English at last (the language which I was wanted).

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão apenas em um lado do papel
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,     % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    brazil,         % idioma adicional para hifenização
  english% o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}
```

Comment: The question is a bout `abntex2cite`, not `abntex2`.

Comment: although this didn't answered correctly the answer, it helped my with an similar problem - using actually the ``abntex2`` package. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
% Pacotes de citações
%\usepackage[brazil,hyperpageref]{backref}   % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[english,hyperpageref]{backref}   % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT

% CONFIGURAÇÕES DE PACOTES

% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
%\begin{comment}
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Cited in page(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        No citation in text.%
    \or
        Cited in page #2.%
    \else
        Cited #1 times in pages #2.%
    \fi}%
%\end{comment}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. I made your answer displayed as a code snippet. I don't understand your answer at all. So please consider pointing out the key factor of your answer in english.