# Sorting bibliography by specific first author name and then year

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am using biblatex package. I am including all bibitems in a document. I want to sort items first by the author X when he is first author, seconds etc and then by year. Is there any simple way of going it?

**Update:**

Here is an example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fruits,
  title = {The apple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Straw Berry and Annoying Orange},
  year = {2015}
}
@book{fruits2,
  title = {The pineapple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange, Straw Berry and Tom Ato},
  year = {2015}
}
@book{fruits3,
  title = {Thank your for your attention},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Tom Ato, Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year = {2014}
}
@book{fruits4,
  title = {Advance title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Cu Cumber, Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year = {2014}
}
@book{fruits5,
  title = {Fancy title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Hello world 

\nocite{fruits,fruits2,fruits3,fruits4,fruits5}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in:
 [image: Result of the above code]

What I want is to first sort by when Annoying Orange is first author and then sort by years, further sort by when Annoying Orange is second author and then by year etc.

so that the significants of the authorship is emphasized for a particular author.

Comment: Can you please show us some code what you are doing ...

Comment: You will find that your name lists are not properly formatted, it should be `Name One and Name Two and Name Three`, not `Name One, Name Two and Name Three`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a fully automatic solution for this is easily implemented, but regex-Biber wizards might surprise me here. So this solution will require some manual work.

First of all, you need to input name list correctly. That is all names have to be separated by an `and`. Do not say `author = {Cu Cumber, Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},`, correct is `author = {Cu Cumber and Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},`. See [How to write properly multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864).

Then you would need to add `sortname = {Annoying Orange}` to all fields.

Finally comes the trick. Add `presort = {<n>},` to the entry if "Annoying Orange" is the *n*-th author.

```
@book{fruits,
  title     = {The apple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Straw Berry and Annoying Orange},
  year      = {2015},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits2,
  title     = {The pineapple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Annoying Orange and Straw Berry and Tom Ato},
  year      = {2015},
  presort   = {1},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits3,
  title     = {Thank your for your attention},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Tom Ato and Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2014},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits4,
  title     = {Advance title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Cu Cumber and Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2014},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits5,
  title     = {Fancy title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2013},
  presort   = {1},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
```

Then all entries are ordered first by the position `Annoying Orange` takes, then by year.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fruits,
  title     = {The apple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Straw Berry and Annoying Orange},
  year      = {2015},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits2,
  title     = {The pineapple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Annoying Orange and Straw Berry and Tom Ato},
  year      = {2015},
  presort   = {1},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits3,
  title     = {Thank your for your attention},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Tom Ato and Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2014},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits4,
  title     = {Advance title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Cu Cumber and Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2014},
  presort   = {2},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits5,
  title     = {Fancy title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor    = {Straw Berry},
  author    = {Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year      = {2013},
  presort   = {1},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
@book{fruits6,
  title     = {Very Advance title},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  author    = {Cu Cumber and Peachy Pear and Annoying Orange},
  year      = {2015},
  presort   = {3},
  sortname  = {Annoying Orange},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]