# Biblatex/Biber not resolving citation if more than 3 authors cited

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using Biblatex and biber for my citation needs, but I have the problem, that one citation remains undefined, if I cite more than 3 authors, with 3 it shows up, with more than that it is undefined!
Anyone had this problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Hi, sounds strange. I think we need a bit [more information](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/). Did you run biber again?

Comment: Providing a minimal example is not that easy, as it is a huge template file. It works like that
author       = {Crispin Cowan, Perry Wagle, Calton Pu and Stevie Beattie and Jonathan Walpole},

but not like that

author       = {Crispin Cowan, Perry Wagle, Calton Pu, and Stevie Beattie and Jonathan Walpole},

This one comma does it somehow! I'm running PdfLatex + biblatex + pdflatex(2x)!

Comment: authors should always be separated by `and` (as far as I know). So your line should be `author = {Cowan, Crispin and Wagle, Perry and Pu, Calton and Beattie, Stevie and Walpole, Jonathan}`

Comment: YOU SHALT NOT USE COMMAS TO DELIMIT AUTHORS. Use `and` instead. *If you picture that grey bearded man from lord of the rings saying that, you will never forget it again*

Comment: In case you speak german, please have a look at [Literaturverzeichnisse mit LaTeX](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md), [Modifizieren eines biblatex Stils](http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/), [minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme](http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage) and [LaTeX-Vorlagen](http://www.niederberger.com.de/latex-vorlagen).

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [How to write properly multiple authors in bibtex file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864).

Comment: @moewe Agreed. I cast the first vote.

Comment: @Johannes_B *He that is without duplicate among you, let him first cast a vote at the post.* `;-)` Close voted seconded, of course.

Comment: Don't ignore the biber messages (in the .blg). It normally complains quite obviously if an authorlist contains too much commas.

Comment: @moewe :-) Had something similar in my head.

Comment: Once again, thanks to all of you :) and yes, I will read this, thanks a lot :)