# Troubles when trying to cite St\"{o}mer-Verlet in "title" field of a bib entry

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a paper on the advancement of Stömer-Verlet method using the Elsevier template. However, I have a challenge when trying to cite. Take for example, in mybib

```
@article{Hairer03,
    title   = "Geometric numerical integration illustrated by the St\"{o}rmer–Verlet method",
    journal = "Acta Numer.",
    volume  = "12",
    pages   = "399--450",
    year    = "2003",
    doi     = "doi: 10.1017/S0962492902000144",
    author  = "{E. Hairer, C. Lubich and G. Wanner}"}
```

If I type

```
title   = "Geometric numerical integration illustrated by the Stormer–Verlet method",
```

it will run but will not run if I type

```
title   = "Geometric numerical integration illustrated by the St\"{o}rmer–Verlet method",
```

In this case, what can I do?

Comment: Can you show us a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? What is the "Elesevier template" you refer to? Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: Have you tried `St{\"{o}}rmer`? The entire non-ascii letter has to be in braces.

Comment: BTW: `author  = "{E. Hairer, C. Lubich and G. Wanner}"` is wrong, it should be `author  = "E. Hairer and C. Lubich and G. Wanner"` (no double braces and names separated with `and`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864)

Comment: @moewe or just remove the `"..."` , `{...}` is just fine for bibtex entries.

Comment: @daleif That's also possible, but since all other fields are delimited with `"..."` `author = "E. Hairer and C. Lubich and G. Wanner",` is more 'consistent'. In fact I prefer `{...}`, but that really does not matter.

Comment: @ Mr daleif, I tried {\"{o}} but it's still not working. @ Mr Mico, I'll check your link.

Comment: Please be more specific about what "it's still not working" entails. E.g., after chaning the entry in the bib file, did you (a) re-run BibTeX and only then (b) re-run LaTeX?

Comment: The please post a full minimal example including information about which bibtex style are being used. Otherwise we'll have to keep guessing. Testing on something as cloas as possible yto your real document is a lot easier.

Comment: Alright, I ran them both in a folder, that is, the latex file and its "mybib" file. Here is an edited portion of my latex code;

Comment: \begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}
   \title{my title}
  \author{Authors' list}
  \address{Our addresses}
 \section*{References}
\bibliography{mybibfilea}
\end{document}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your bib entry. How to typeset `Störmer` may not be the most severe one.

- You use the unicode-encoded form of the "en-dash" glyph: `–` between the words "Stormer" and "Verlet". Do use `--` instead, *unless* you use a unicode-aware TeX engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX) to compile the document.
- In order to keep BibTeX from lowercasing the names `Störmer` and `Verlet` in the `title` field, encase them in curly braces.
- Abbreviating the journal's name to `Acta Numer.` seems quite unnecessary. Instead, do write `Acta Numerica`. If you feel ambitious, you could set up a string variable that encodes whether or not the journal name should be abbreviated. If your paper is intended for submission to an academic journal, the journal will likely have its own, "house" rules regarding journal name abbreviations. Don't make their job more difficult by providing possibly non-standard abbrevations.
- Remove "doi: " from the `doi` field and make sure to use a bibliography style that knows how to handle the `doi` field. Aside: If you don't already do so, be sure to load the `url` package.
- To separate the authors' names in the `author` field, use the keyword `and`, *not* commas.
- I'd also use the authors' full given names in the `author` field, and leave it up to the bibliography style to determine whether full or abbreviated given names should be shown in the formatted bibliography.
- Writing `St{\"o}rmer` instead of `Störmer` in the `title` field should not be necessary if you either employ a unicode-aware TeX engine or (in case you employ pdfLaTeX, which is not fully unicode-aware) load the `inputenc` package with the option `utf8`.

The fully modified bib entry should therefore look something like this:

```
@article{Hairer03,
  author       = "Ernst Hairer and Christian Lubich and Gerhard Wanner",
  title        = "Geometric numerical integration illustrated by the
                  {St{\"o}rmer--Verlet} method",
  journal      = "Acta Numerica",
  volume       = 12,
  pages        = "399--450",
  year         = 2003,
  doi          = "10.1017/S0962492902000144",
}
```

If you use a bibliography style which doesn't process the `doi` field, but if you somehow believe it's really necessary to show the DOI string, just change the field

```
  doi          = "10.1017/S0962492902000144",
```

to

```
  note          = "doi: \url{10.1017/S0962492902000144}",
```

The `note` field is always processed, by pretty much every bibliography style that's out there, somewhere.
(You did remember to load the `url` package, right?)

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Hairer03,
  author       = "Ernst Hairer and Christian Lubich and Gerhard
                  Wanner",
  title        = "Geometric numerical integration illustrated by the
                  {St{\"o}rmer--Verlet} method",
  journal      = "Acta Numerica",
  volume       = 12,
  pages        = "399--450",
  year         = 2003,
  doi          = "10.1017/S0962492902000144",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % any bib style that processes the 'doi' field
\usepackage{url} % to process the contents of the 'doi' field

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg - Good point. I'll edit the bullet point accordingly.

Comment: @ Mico, thank you very much. God bless you all for the answers. I was able to resolve it that same day I asked the question. Thanks all