# extsizes and natbib / biblatex troubling around

Tags: biblatex, natbib, extsizes

I took the template from [rsc.org](https://www.rsc.org/journals-books-databases/journal-authors-reviewers/author-tools-services) and adjusted it for the needs recommended for this work. Now, `extsizes` makes trouble, so I excluded it with every line referring to it. `natbib` was also troubling around, so I replaced it with `biblatex` which normally doesn't make any trouble in my documents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[left=18mm,right=18mm,top=47mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font={stretch=1.125,small,sf},labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{222,217,201}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,color=black,contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node at ([xshift=-10cm,yshift=-19mm] current page.north east)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{headerfile}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\title{my title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.~}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.~}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \makeFNbottom
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{15pt}{25}}
    \renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12pt}{17}}
    \renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{10pt}{14}}
    \renewcommand\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize{7pt}{10}}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
    \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}            
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\@thefnmark\,}#1}
    \makeatother 
    \sectionfont{\sffamily\Large}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsubsectionfont{\bf}
    \setstretch{1.125}
    \setlength{\skip\footins}{0.8cm}
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.25cm}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{4pt}{4pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15pt}{1pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \include{titlepage}
    \newpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lfoot{name of subject -- 2018}
    \rfoot{shortname, 2018, \textbf{subtopic 1}| \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{6.5mm}
    \setlength\bibsep{1pt}
    \newlength{\figrulesep} 
    \setlength{\figrulesep}{0.5\textfloatsep} 
    \newcommand{\topfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}}}
    \newcommand{\botfigrule}{\vspace*{-2pt}\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}}}
    \newcommand{\dblfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}}
    \twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
%       \vspace{3cm}
        \sffamily
        \LARGE{\textbf{Our topic we're writing about}}\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}\\
        \large{me, the author}\\
        \normalsize{some introduction - \lipsum[1]}\\
    \end{@twocolumnfalse} \vspace{0.6cm}]
    \renewcommand*\rmdefault{bch}\normalfont\upshape
    \rmfamily
    \section*{}
    \vspace{-1cm}
    \section*{theory}
        \lipsum[2]\\one\cite{papere}, two\cite{paperz}, three\cite{paperd}, four\cite{paperv}
        \paragraph*{first subtopic}
            picture here (Abb.~\ref{pic})
            \begin{figure}[!h]\centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example}
                \caption{picture.\cite{papere}.}\label{pic}
            \end{figure}
    \section*{what we did and how}
        \lipsum[3].
        \subsection*{nice title 1}
            \lipsum[4]
        \subsection*{nice title 2}
            \lipsum[5]
    \section*{data and discussion}
        \lipsum[6]
        \subsection*{disc. 1}
            some text\cite{paperz}.\\
            some text (Tab.~\ref{asdf}) for writing. bla bla bla lorem ipsum dolor et piscit.
            \begin{table}[!h]\small
                \centering
                \caption{fac animalia ad trahit.}\label{asdf}
                \begin{tabular}{l|cccc}
                    value&no 1&no 2&no 3\\ \hline
                    v\textsubscript{max}&1&2&3\\
                    v\textsubscript{max}&4&5&6\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
    \section*{ending}
        \lipsum
%   \bibliography{sources} %You need to replace "rsc" on this line with the name of your .bib file
%   \bibliographystyle{rsc} %the RSC's .bst file
    \vspace{2cm}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I know that there may be packages having the need to be included before specific others. Could it be that I just got "the wrong" order for my packages used?

My `sources.bib`, which gives me output shown after:

```
@ARTICLE{papere,
title={Synthesis of some polymer via some Polymerization and Its Evaluation in some field},
author={Bugnon, Lucienne; Morton, Colin J. H.; Novak, Petr; Vetter, Jens; Nesvadba, Peter},
journal={chemistry},
year={2000},
volume={100},
pages={1234--5678},
number={1},
}
@ARTICLE{paperz,
title={Improved Synthetic Procedure and Molecular Weight Control},
author={Neef, C. J.; Ferraris, J. P.},
journal={matter},
year={2000},
volume={100},
pages={1234--5678},
number={7},
}
@ARTICLE{paperd,
title={Synthesis of some polymer via some Polymerization and Its Evaluation in some field},
author={Lucienne Bugnon, Colin J. H. Morton, Petr Novak, Jens Vetter, Peter Nesvadba},
journal={chemistry},
year={2000},
volume={100},
pages={1234--5678},
number={1},
}
@ARTICLE{paperv,
title={Improved Synthetic Procedure and Molecular Weight Control},
author={C. J. Neef; J. P. Ferraris},
journal={matter},
year={2000},
volume={100},
pages={1234--5678},
number={7},
}
```

The output is from an earlier file version without that problem, but with a wrong citation "in exchange".

```
1 P. N. J. V. P. N. Lucienne Bugnon, Colin J. H. Morton,
    Chem. Mater., 2007, 19, 2910–2914.
2 C. J. N. J. P. Ferraris, Macromolecules, 2000, 33,
    2311–2314.
```

Comment: Could you explain what troubles you are getting? What do you expect to see, what do you see instead? Can you add a screenshot of the output, or an excerpt of the `.log` file?

Comment: Several things: don't load `\usepackage{ngerman}`, `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` already gives you German localisation. The length `\bibsep` is unknown, so you need to delete the line `\setlength\bibsep{1pt}`. We also don't have your `headerfile`. And you seem to have a few `\\` that are inappropriate.

Comment: Your `.bib` file input is also wrong. Names *must* be separated with `and` and not with commas or semicolons regardless of the desired output. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: @moewe : my errors:
I ExtSizes: It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can. -> extsizes.sty
II biblatex: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend: -> blx-bibtex.def
III Undefined control sequence -> mwe.tex -> 45
IV Emergency stop -> mwe.tex -> 45

Comment: The first few messages are 'only' warnings. The undefined control sequence is an error, but you don't tell us which sequence is undefined. Your document is quite a mess at the moment. Would it be possible to start over with a more minimal approach?

Comment: `\begin{document}` is marked as undefined.

Comment: Well, if there is one thing we can be sure that is defined, it's `\begin{document}`. Did you remove `\usepackage{ngerman}`? I could get your MWE to work with the changes mentioned in my answer. But really even the small bits of your document that you have shown us is a terrible mess. You should seriously consider starting anew. Since you seem to read German, have a look at https://komascript.de/latexvorlage

Comment: `\begin{document}` was marked as undefined; `\setlength\bibsep{1pt}` seems to need another package. I commented it out and now everything works just fine.

Comment: As I said in my answer "The length `\bibsep` is unknown, so you can't redefine it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for `biblatex` is that you load the `ngerman` package. That package is deprecated and should be removed. You should use

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

instead (as you already do).

Your `.bib` file uses the wrong format for author names. You need to separate names with `and`, for example

```
author={Neef, C. J. and Ferraris, J. P.},
```

Your code has a lot of other issues as well. For one you probably load far more packages than you actually need.
The length `\bibsep` is unknown, so you can't redefine it.
And you have at least in your example several `\\`'s that can't be used in these places, because they come after `\lipsum` that already end a paragraph.