# Problem with accents in .Bib file

Tags: bibliographies, accents, subfiles

I've been trying to find the source of  problem without success, It keeps coming.

I'm trying to move from writing linear to modular, since the notes are getting bigger, so I'm using the `subfile` package. And since this, everything went wrong with the bibliography because all the special characters of the `.bib` aren't shown, I keep getting the  **Finished with exit code 1**. Whereas working linearly it didn't happen. Even though the preamble is the same for both.

The `main.tex` looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel} %Since I'm writing in spanish I need it!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Even using this, It didn't work
 \usepackage{subfiles} %To work modular
 \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
 \usepackage{longtable,array,tabularx,booktabs,lscape}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
 \usepackage{vmargin} 
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{color} 
 \usepackage{multicol} 
 \usepackage{tcolorbox} 
 \usepackage{accents} 
 \usepackage{cancel} 
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{hyperref} 
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %Since I just have subsections in the whole doc
%Just config of the table of contents
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, 
linktoc=all,     
linkcolor=magenta,  
}
%New Enviroments   
\newtheorem{Def}{{Definición}}[subsection]
\newtheorem{Lema}{{Lema}}[subsection]
\newtheorem{Obs}{{Observación}}[subsection]
\newtheorem{Prop}{{Proposición}}[subsection]
\newtheorem{Teo}{{Teorema}}[subsection]
% To work with  vmargins
\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{2 cm}       
{1.5cm}                        
{16 cm}                      
{23.42cm}                    
{15pt}                          
{1cm}                          
{1pt}                             
{1cm}                           
%Page Style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\bfseries Notes }
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{ }
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.10pt}


%NEW COMMANDS
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathbb{W}}
\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\subfile{Section1}
\subfile{Section2}
\subfile{Section3}
\subfile{Section4}
\subfile{Section5}
\subfile{Section6}


\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{./AMBib}


\end{document}
```

On the other hand, my `.bib` document looks like this:

```
@book{OM,
Author = {Ó Searcóid,Mícheál},
Publisher = {Springer Verlag London Limited},
Title = {Metric Spaces},
Year = {2007}
}

@book{PM,
Author = {Pedro J. Miana },
Publisher = {Departamento de Matemáticas, Universidad de Zaragoza   },
Title = {Curso de Análisis Funcional: Notas de Clase},
Year = {2006},
}


@book{PJHP,
Author = {Pedro Jose Herrero Piñeyro  },
Publisher = {Universidad de Murcia},
Title = {Topología de Espacios Métricos},
Year = {2010},
}

@book{Kolmorov,
Author = {A. N. Kolmogorov , S. V. Fomin },
Publisher = {Editorial Mir},
Title = {Teoria de las ecuaciones y del análisis funcional },
Year = {1975},
}

@book{Jost,
Author = {Jürgen Jost },
Publisher = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
Title = {Postmodern Analysis},
Year = {2005},
}
```

The problem isn't with the cross-reference or so, it does its job. The thing is for example that **Ó Searcóid,Mícheál** is shown without all the accented letters. I know that I can change every special character, for example `Jürgen`  to `J\"{u}rgen` as well as for the others, but I had no problem before (working linearly). Is there something that am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Several things: You are *not* using `biblatex` as your tag suggests. You are using plain old BibTeX. BibTeX officially can't really deal properly with the full range of Unicode characters - I can normally get my BibTeX to work with non-ASCII chars, but the sorting will be off. Unfortunately, your example is not really an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/). I don't really have time at the moment, so I can't test your code since it would require me to make up quite a few things from scratch. Help us to help you with a good MWE.

Comment: ...  Your input for author names is incorrect: Several authors need to separated with `and` not with a comma, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864: `Author = {A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin},`. I don't think you really need `subfiles`' `\subfile` here, standard `\include` or even `\input` would probably be enough already. It also greatly helps us if you can get the `.blg` file of your BibTeX run with more details errors and warnings. The `the Finished with exit code 1.` thing is only what your editor shows.

Comment: Thanks you all, at the end the problem was because there was a somehow interference with the Fourier package. I had to get rid of it to have it as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the best would be to use `biblatex` and `biber` instead of `bibtex`.  Then you can write letters with accents in your `bib` file which will be printed too.

Please see that you have to write two or more authors like this:

```
@book{Kolmorov,
  Author = {A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin },
```

To concatenate two or more authors use `and` instead of your used `,`!

To call `biblatex` and name the used bib file (here `\jobname.bib`, because I used package `filecontents` to have bib file and TeX code together in one compiling MWE) use

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} % <================================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

Please see that option `backend=biber` requires `biber` instead `bibtex`.

To print the bibliography in the document use `\printbibliography`.

Please read the documentation of `biblatex` (`texdoc biblatex`) to customize it at your needs ...

With the following MWE (I deleted all packages not relevant for this problem)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{OM,
  Author = {Ó Searcóid, Mícheál},
  Publisher = {Springer Verlag London Limited},
  Title = {Metric Spaces},
  Year = {2007},
}
@book{PM,
  Author = {Pedro J. Miana },
  Publisher = {Departamento de Matemáticas, Universidad de Zaragoza   },
  Title = {Curso de Análisis Funcional: Notas de Clase},
  Year = {2006},
}
@book{PJHP,
  Author = {Pedro Jose Herrero Piñeyro  },
  Publisher = {Universidad de Murcia},
  Title = {Topología de Espacios Métricos},
  Year = {2010},
}
@book{Kolmorov,
  Author = {A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin },
  Publisher = {Editorial Mir},
  Title = {Teoria de las ecuaciones y del análisis funcional },
  Year = {1975},
}
@book{Jost,
  Author = {Jürgen Jost },
  Publisher = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
  Title = {Postmodern Analysis},
  Year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel} %Since I'm writing in spanish I need it!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Even using this, It didn't work

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} % <================================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\usepackage{vmargin} % outdated
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %Since I just have subsections in the whole doc
%Just config of the table of contents
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, 
  linktoc=all,     
  linkcolor=magenta,  
}

% To work with  vmargins
%\setpapersize{A4}
%\setmargins{2 cm}       
%{1.5cm}                        
%{16 cm}                      
%{23.42cm}                    
%{15pt}                          
%{1cm}                          
%{1pt}                             
%{1cm}                           


\begin{document}
\sffamily

\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliography{\jobname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with name Wösten in the .bib file. It shows up corretly in Lyx and in Jabref bib file, but not in the generated bibliography at the end of the pdf.document. The only thing I had to do is change the name in

W"{o}sten

In the .bib file. For a few letters in the file is this perhaps the simplest solution. Since a bibfile is plain text, a few global replacements should suffice.

Comment: OP already knows it is a possible solution. He asked how to solve his issue without changing how he wrote names.