# Biblatex: First and Lastname of first Author not divided by commas, but works with the second author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, author

So this is my .bib entry

```
@book{FUR,
    Author = {Furht, Borko; Villanustre, Flavio},
    Publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
    Title = {Big Data Technologies and Applications},
    Year = {2016}}
```

I use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

The result I want is:

Furht, Borko; Villanustre, Flavio (2016).
    *Big Data Technologies and Applications.*
    Springer International Publishing

what I get is:

Furht Borko; Villanustre, Flavio (2016).
    *Big Data Technologies and Applications.*
    Springer International Publishing

The first Authors first and lastname are not divided by a comma, any suggestion how i could fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. Please consider adding a full MWE to your question, that makes it much easier to get started answering your question and makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing. `style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear` is equivalent to `style=authoryear` since `style` sets both `bibstyle` and `citestyle`.

Comment: Oops, I didnt't see the `Author = {Furht, Borko; Villanustre, Flavio},` that is wrong. Names need to be separated with an `and` in the input, you need `Author = {Furht, Borko and Villanustre, Flavio},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: Any news here? Did any of that help?

Comment: If there is no feedback here soon I'm going to vote as duplicate of  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 since that is the primary problem here.

Comment: Since your profile shows that you were last seen after I posted my comment I will vote to close this question as a duplicate. Please edit your question with more details if you disagree.