# Commas in bibliography in latex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to put commas in the bibliography in between the names of the authors in Latex but it isn't working. Also, I have putted "and" between their names in the bibtex but it didn't work (it is showing me the word and when compiling instead of a comma!) I am using unsrt style. Does anyone have an idea what to do in that case?

```
@book{Emile,
    title={The River},
    author={Emile Colombos, Rita James and Tom Hardy },
    volume={7},
    year={2000} }
```

Comment: it needs to be "and" not "," as "," is used to separate name parts, presumably if you got multiple ands as in the output, like "tom and dick and harry" then there was a syntax  error in your bib file but hard to guess what is wrong if you show no example.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @book{Emile,
  title={The River},
  author={Emile Colombos, Rita James and Tom Hardy },
  volume={7},
  year={2000}
}

Comment: This is what I wrote in the bibtex

Comment: @E.s. `author={Emile Colombos and Rita James and Tom Hardy},`

Comment: the comma between Colombos and Rita doesn't appear when compiling and the "and" between James and Tom appears like a word between them when compiling not like a comma

Comment: Thanks it worked! But in the unsrt style there's no comma between the author and the title is it true ? It shows me a point between them

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        author={Emile Colombos, Rita James and Tom Hardy },
```

means a two-author work where the first author has the compound surname "Emile Colombos" and first names "Rita James`  as authors can be specified as "David Carlisle" or "Carlisle, David".

You want to specify three authors so:

```
        author={Emile Colombos and Rita James and Tom Hardy},
```