# Inbook citation not showing the section title

Tags: biblatex

reference for book section is not showing properly where the book section title is missing:[image: missing before in]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
               headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
               numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
               captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=nature, 
  citestyle=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  natbib=true, 
  uniquename=false, 
  date=year,
  url=false,
  doi=false, 
  isbn=false,
  mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
this is not showing properly
\citep{CASESMITH2006}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

in biblio.bib:

```
@incollection{CASESMITH2006,
address = {Massachusetts},
author = {Case-Smith, Jane},
booktitle = {Hand Function in the Child},
chapter = {Hand Skill},
doi = {10.1016/B978-032303186-8.50010-1},
edition = {2},
editor = {{Henderson, Anne; Pehoski}, Charlene},
isbn = {9780323031868},
pages = {117--141},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {{Hand Skill Development in the Context of Infants' Play: Birth to 2 Years}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/B9780323031868500101},
year = {2006}
}
```

Comment: I will check in a few minutes, but I can tell you already that `editor = {{Henderson, Anne; Pehoski}, Charlene},` is very wrong. It should be `editor = {Henderson, Anne and Pehoski, Charlene},`. Names must always be separated with `and`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: @moewe I do notice that about the naming, but Mendeley generated the naming automatically and it's quite annoying to change it everytime I update my list of references

Comment: Ugh, Mendeley. There should be a way to input the name so that it is exported correctly. If there is not you should contact the developers and complain about that. The output you get now is seriously broken and wrong.

Answer (score 3):

By default `biblatex-nature` suppresses titles of `@inbook`/`@incollection` entries. You can get the titles back with `intitle=true` for `@inbook` and `@incollection`.

Incidentally, there is a similar setting for titles of `@article` entries. `articletitle=true` is the default and displays article titles, but with `articletitle=false` you can suppress them.

See also the [`biblatex-nature` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-nature/biblatex-nature.pdf) about `articletitl` and `intitle`.

Note that the name format of the `editor` field was incorrect (see [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864)) and that normally the `chapter` field holds a numeric value (the chapter number) and not a (shortened) copy of the chapter title.

I would also like to mention that the combination of `authoryear` citation style and (numeric) `nature` bibliography style is not particularly fortunate. In a long bibliography with many entries it might be quite hard to find an entry from its author-year label since the year is located near the end, while the author name is at the front. The numbers in the bibliography also have no connection to anything else in the document and just add visual noise, in fact I believe they distract from the author name and make things harder to find.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=nature,
%  articletitle=false,
  intitle=true,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  uniquename=false,
  date=year,
  url=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  mincitenames=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{CASESMITH2006,
  address   = {Massachusetts},
  author    = {Case-Smith, Jane},
  booktitle = {Hand Function in the Child},
  chapter   = {7},
  doi       = {10.1016/B978-032303186-8.50010-1},
  edition   = {2},
  editor    = {Henderson, Anne and Pehoski, Charlene},
  isbn      = {9780323031868},
  pages     = {117--141},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  title     = {Hand Skill Development in the Context of Infants' Play: Birth to 2 Years},
  year      = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
this is not showing properly
\citep{CASESMITH2006,sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Case-Smith, J. *Hand Skill Development in the Context of Infants’ Play: Birth to 2 Years* in *Hand Function in the Child* (eds Henderson, A. & Pehoski, C.) 2nd ed., 117–141 (Elsevier, Massachusetts, 2006).]

Note finally that you were using outdated and deprecated options to `scrreprt`, you should see warnings about that in the `.log` file.

Comment: Interesting. However, I get this error /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:11970:
Package ke
yval Error: intitle undefined.

Comment: @Sharah In that case you are using an outdated version of `biblatex-nature`. The option was added in version 1.3 from October 2016: https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/commit/0a58f60bb385e8f8c383d156434470649840dc99 Make an update.

Comment: Since I am using Overleaf, is there's a way to use the latest version of `biblatex-nature`?

Comment: @Sharah Well `biblatex-nature` only really consists of `nature.cbx` and `nature.bbx`. I assume you could get them from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-nature and upload them with your project. This might work, but it could also go wrong in case `biblatex-nature` uses some new features of `biblatex` that the version of Overleaf does not support yet.

Comment: I see. Alright I will find some work to go around that. Anyway, what do you mean by  outdated and deprecated options to scrreprt? I do not see any warning

Comment: @Sharah Again, that might be a version issue. On my up-to-date system I get ```Package typearea Warning: You've used obsolete option `BCOR5mm'. Usage of this option indicates an old document and changes compatibility level using `BCOR=5mm,version=first, enabledeprecatedfontcommands' that may result in further warnings. If you don't want this, you should simply replace option `BCOR5mm' by `BCOR=5mm'.``` But on Overleaf's older system maybe one doesn't get these warnings, or they are not shown.

Comment: It's quite surprising that Overleaf wouldn't use the latest version for everything. Thanks for the help I will KIV this post and update if the solution works for me

Comment: @Sharah Not at all. It is well known that ShareLaTeX and Overleaf use older versions of TeX live. They can't update their systems continuously. Stability (even of packages) is much more important than being at the edge of TeX development for them. (See also https://www.overleaf.com/blog/435-tex-live-upgrade-november-2016#.W4ZrVLhpFEY)