# et al extension using dinat natbib style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using natbib with dinat style and the "et al" extension doesn't show up which it does in every side I'm looking for more information as here

[natbib styles](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_bibliography_styles)

and I'm wondering what the reason for this is.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib} % for extended citations
\bibliographystyle{dinat} % reference style


\begin{document}
Hello world......................
This is a citation \citep*{Mueller2018}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{literatur}

\end{document}
```

and here the bib file

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Mueller2018,
  author  = {Mueller, Thomas; Peter Mueller; Klaus Mueller; Maier Herbert},
  title   = {On the testing of natbib},
  journal = {my personal journal},
  year    = {2018},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Hoping for input.
I'm also wondering if the separation using semicolon ; in the author list is correct. At least that's the only way I get a proper author list display working.

Comment: Names must be separated with `and` and not with commas or semicolons in the `.bib` file, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. So `author  = {Mueller, Thomas and Peter Mueller and Klaus Mueller and Maier Herbert},` would be correct. It's too late for me to investigate the "et al." issue.

Comment: As @moewe pointed out, the author names should be separated by `and`. After correcting this, your mwe produces `(Mueller, Mueller, Mueller und Herbert, 2018)` for citation, `[Mueller u.a. 2018]` for label, and `Mueller, Thomas ; Mueller, Peter ; Mueller, Klaus ; Herbert, Maier` for author names in the bibliography. Where do you want an `et al` to show up?

Comment: I guess for et al I have to use plainnat.bst or others instead of dinat or changing \citep*{} ?? But for dinat I like the way the bibliography is organized with the citation symbol being in square brackets [ Mueller 2018 ] while plainnat is just plain without any bracket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors must be separated with an `and` and not with commas or semicolons regardless of the expected output in the bibliography. See [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864). So

```
author = {Mueller, Thomas and Peter Mueller and Klaus Mueller and Maier Herbert},
```

would be correct.

---

You may want to consider using `natdin` instead of `dinat`. `natdin` is from 2006, while `dinat` is from 2000. [`l2tabu`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) for example advises `natdin` over `dinat`. I would normally suggest `biblatex` and Biber nowadays (but then I may be biased).

Both styles write "u. a." instead of "et al." and both styles have facilities to change this, but in both cases that means you have to edit a copy of the `.bst` style.

The general strategy is the same

1. Locate the style you want to change on your machine. You can find the file path by typing `kpsewhich dinat.bst` or `kspewhich natdin.bst` into a terminal. Failing that get the files from CTAN: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/dinat or https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505
2. Copy the file to a place where LaTeX can find it (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf), the directory of your current document will do just fine, and rename it. *You must rename the file if you modify it, this is part of the license.* Let's say the new names are `dinat-etal.bst` and `natdin-etal.bst`
3. - Open `dinat-etal.bst` and go to line 122

     ```
     FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "u.\,a." }
     ```

     replace it with

     ```
     FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "et~al." }
     ```
   - Open `natdin-etal.bst`, go to line 188 and replace

     ```
     FUNCTION { ua.etal } { " u.\,a." }
     ```

     with

     ```
     FUNCTION { ua.etal } { " et~al." }
     ```

     If you want to you can also change the string for and from "u." to "und" in the next line.
4. Save the file.
5. Use `\bibliographystyle{dinat-etal}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{dinat}` and `\bibliographystyle{natdin-etal}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{natdin}`.

You will want to use `\citep` and not `\citep*` to obtain a short "et al." citation. The starred version will try to print the full author list, thus suppressing any "et al.".

You probably also want to load `natbib` with the `square` option.

Use a package like  `tocbibind` or a class option (KOMA) to get the bibliography to the TOC, don't add it manually with `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin-etal}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Mueller2018,
  author  = {Mueller, Thomas and Peter Mueller and Klaus Mueller and Maier Herbert},
  title   = {On the testing of natbib},
  journal = {my personal journal},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a citation \citep{Mueller2018}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a citation [Mueller et al., 2018]//References//[Mueller et al. 2018] Mueller, Thomas ; Mueller, Peter ; Mueller, Klaus ; Herbert, Maier: On the testing of natbib. In: my personal journal (2018)]

Comment: I guess I have to say big thanks! couple of questions: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}` what is the problem with this? It works so why not use it? `If you want to you can also change the string for and from "u." to "und" in the next line.` Looking through the .bst file it seems it is dedicated to german speakers, right? So I would have to change it to `and` instead of `und` since I'm writing in english? `\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}...` Why do you prefer doing it in the .tex file and not in an external file?

Comment: @Diger As you use it with `\newpage` and before `\bibliography` there is not that much that could go wrong with `\addcontentsline` (things generally go wrong if you issue `\addcontentsline` after `\bibliography` and you have a multi-page bibliography). Still I think it is a good habit not to use specialised commands like `\addcontentsline` in the document especially when there are packages or options that do this for you. Yes both `natdin` and `dinat` are for German texts following DIN recommendations. If you write in English I suggest you don't use the styles at all. ...

Comment: ... There are other terms you would have to translate (`editor` -> Herausgaber, ...) and some of the choices of the style are already questionable in German typography (spaces before semicolons - the norm in French texts, but not in German texts; small caps for names - OK I actually like that, but they are far rarer in English texts than in German texts) but almost unheard of in English texts. For MWEs on this site I always use `filecontents` because that allows me to copy and paste just one file. I don't use `filecontents` when I write documents for myself.

Comment: I have to think about it, but if I change the styles which do you recommend that are close to dinat/natdin?

Comment: @Diger I guess that depends on your definition of closeness. I would have suggested `apalike`, but I would not use that together with `natbib`. You could also try `plainnat` (you won't get the label in the bibliography) if you want to stick with `natbib` (probably as `\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}`). `agsm` is another often-used author-year style that works with `natbib`. Maybe `biblatex` is an option, then you can start with `authoryear` and build your won style fairly easily.

Comment: I'm though wondering why german vowels do not work if these style files are done for german. I get an error using ö,ä,ü,ß.

Comment: @Diger Where exactly do you use the umlauts and what error do you get? I don't know if you can use non-ASCII chars in `.bst` files, but they should in principle work in your `.bib` file. (BIbTeX can't really deal with non-ASCII chars, but it just passes them on as binary data and does not touch them.) If you'd like to get your umlauts working, I suggest you ask a new question with an MWE. Don't forget to mention the file encoding of both your `.tex` and `.bib file (they should match, otherwise things may go wrong).

Comment: `Where exactly do you use the umlauts and what error do you get?` Well some names have Umlaute such as "Müller" and so while compiling the .tex document it returns an error complaing about the ü. Of course there are no problems writing the vowels into the .bib file. Do you need the exact error output?

Comment: @Diger I not only need the exact error output, I also need the input that lets me reproduce the error. Please open a new question with a minimal working example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Make sure to double-check the encoding of your `.tex` and `.bib` file and report them in the question as well.

Comment: That said, `ü` should work in your `.bib` file provided your `.bib` file and `.tex` file use the same encoding (and that encoding is declared to `inputenc` - in this case you'd need UTF-8). As I already said, BibTeX can't really deal with non-ASCII chars, which means it won't sort them correctly, it will just pass them through unchanged and uninterpreted. All that means that normally things should just work, so if they don't work for you, there must be something going on. We can only find out what that is if you give us more information in form of a proper new question with an MWE.