# Problem creating two bibliographies with any package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, multibib, bibulous

I need to create two bibliographies for my thesis. One for articles and one for books. I have to seperate .bib files. I tried to use several packages but none of them worked. Unfotunately I cannot use biblatex because I am using bibulous which is not compatible with biblatex. I read several forum posts related to creating two seperate bibliographies in one document but they were all quite old so I am not sure which of the many packages to create two bibliographies works the best.

I am adding a MWE with my approach with multibib.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4papter] {scrartcl}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bst}
TEMPLATES:
book =  <au>. {<title>} [<address> <year>.]
article = <au>. {<title>} [\textit{<journal>,] [<year>,] [<number>,}] [<pages>.]

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
citelabel = <authorlist.0.last>, <year>
sortkey = <authorlist.0.last><year>

OPTIONS:
namelist_format = last_name_first
use_firstname_initials = False
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}{books.bib}
@Book{sicherheit2018,
  chapter   = {10. Armee als Spiegelbild der Gesellschaft},
  pages     = {170},
  title     = {Sicherheit 2018},
  publisher = {Tresch, Szvircsev Tibor; Wenger, Andrea.},
  year      = {2018},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{articles.bib}
@Article{asmz,
  author  = {Tresch, Tibor Szvircsev and Sokoli, Evgjenije},
  title   = {Schweizer Rekruten mit Migrationshintergrund : motiviert und leistungsbereit},
  journal = {Allgemeine schweizerische Militärzeitschrift},
  year    = {2013},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {40-41},
}


\end{filecontents}

\newcites{ltex}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \citet{asmz} consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
\cite{sicherheit2018}. 




\bibliographystyleltex{test}
\bibliographyltex{books}
\renewcommand{\refname}{articles}
\bibliographystyle{test}
\bibliography{articles}


\end{document}
```

If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please note that you must separate names with `and` not with a semicolon in the source regardless of the desired output: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. It should be `author  = {Tresch, Tibor Szvircsev and Sokoli, Evgjenije},`

Answer (score 2):

Bibulous is a drop-in replacement for BibTeX, so `multibib` with Bibulous should work exactly as it did with BibTeX. Because BibTeX's workflow was not really designed with multiple bibliographies in mind, `multibib` can be a bit awkward to use. Please have a look at the [`multibib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) for more details. In particular LaTeX will need to write a separate `.aux` file for each separate bibliography you want to create and you have to run BibTeX/Bibulous on each file.

Suppose your document

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4papter, nswissgerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bst}
TEMPLATES:
book =  <au>. <title> [<address> <year>.]
inbook =  <au>. \enquote{<title>} in \textit{<booktitle>}[ <address> <year>][, <chapter>], S. <pages>.
article = <au>. <title> \textit{<journal>,[ <year>,][ <number>]}[, <pages>.]

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
authorlist = <author.to_namelist()>
editorlist = <editor.to_namelist()>
authorname.n = [<authorlist.n.prefix> ]<authorlist.n.last>[, <authorlist.n.first>][,  <authorlist.n.suffix>.]
editorname.n = [<editorname.n.prefix> ]<editorname.n.last>[, <editorname.n.first>][,  <editorname.n.suffix>.]
au = <authorname.0>; ...; <authorname.999>
ed = <editorname.0>; ...; <editorname.999>

citelabel = <authorlist.0.last>, <year>
sortkey = <authorlist.0.last><year>

OPTIONS:
namelist_format = last_name_first
use_firstname_initials = False
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}{books.bib}
@inbook{sicherheit2018,
  author    = {Tibor Szvircsev Tresch and Andreas Wenger and Stefano De Rosa 
               and Thomas Ferst and Mauro Giovanoli and Eva Moehlecke de Baseggio
               and Olivia Schneider and Jennifer Victoria Scurrell},
  title     = {Armee als Spiegelbild der Gesellschaft},
  chapter   = {10},
  pages     = {161-184},
  booktitle = {Sicherheit 2018},
  editor    = {Tresch, Szvircsev Tibor and Wenger, Andrea.},
  year      = {2018},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{articles.bib}
@Article{asmz,
  author  = {Tresch, Tibor Szvircsev and Sokoli, Evgjenije},
  title   = {Schweizer Rekruten mit Migrationshintergrund : motiviert und leistungsbereit},
  journal = {Allgemeine schweizerische Militärzeitschrift},
  year    = {2013},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {40-41},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcites{ltex}{Books}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \citet{asmz} consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \citeltex{sicherheit2018}

\bibliographystyleltex{test}
\bibliographyltex{books}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\bibliographystyle{test}
\bibliography{articles}
\end{document}
```

is called `test.tex`.

Compile it with

1. `pdflatex test`
2. `python bibulous.py test.aux`
3. `python bibulous.py ltex.aux`
4. `pdflatex test`
5. `pdflatex test`

to obtain

[image: screenshot of the document with two bibliographies]

Note that I fixed the syntax error mentioned in the comments (names must be separated with `and`) and made other cosmetic changes to your style and `.bib` files.