# Latex biber gives me [0] for cites using JabRef

Tags: biblatex, biber

Hi guys I'm having an unresolvable problem with my LaTeX document (at least for me).

Here are my first two entries from the references file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{FelixWortmann2015,
  author       = {Felix Wortmann, Kristina Fluechter},
  title        = {Internet of Things - Technology and Value Added},
  journal      = {Springer},
  journaltitle = {Business \& Information Systems Engineering},
  year         = {2015},
  date         = {2015-03-27},
  url          = {https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12599-015-0383-3.pdf},
}

@Online{Lueth2016,
  author = {Knud Lasse Lueth},
  title  = {OVERVIEW OF 640+ ENTERPRISE IOT USE CASES},
  year   = {2016},
  date   = {2016-08-11},
  url    = {https://iot-analytics.com/global-overview-640-enterprise-iot-use-cases/},
}
```

Here are my headers for the document:

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\logofile{logo}
\bibliography{references}
```

in my project folder there is an "references.bib" and a "references.bib.bak" file (containing all the sources)

Now when creating my pdf-file i get all [0] instead of the correct number. My texnic center gives me this output:

> pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Repschlaeger2014' on page1 undefined on input line 75
>   pdflatex> There were undefined references.
>   pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file

I get the same warning for a number of citations. Please tell me if you require any more information.

Comment: Did you ever run `biber` on your file, as said in the warning too?

Comment: yeh i ran biber multiple times already. first time running it, it gave me some weird cite numbers like [13],[37] and created no bibliography. The next time running it displayed the bibtexkeys instead of the numbers with a warning saying "Citation 'xxx' on page xx undefined on input line xxx.

Running biber and then bibtex leaves me with the result as seen in the question. Though it's strange that it creates a bibliography when doing so.

Comment: The procedure is to run `pdflatex`... then `biber` and then `pdflatex`... `bibtex` has nothing to do with your document since you are using `biblatex`. So... clear all the aux and similar files and try again with the above procedure

Comment: well wow. i'm quite dumb as it seems. Thank you very much, your procedure resolved the error.

Comment: Welcome! We all learning latex every day... It is something that nobody (except @egreg) can say that is an expert on this. Happy TeXing.

Comment: Multiple authors must be separated with `and`: `author = {Felix Wortmann and Kristina Fluechter},` otherwise Biber (and likewise BibTeX) will not be able to parse the name correctly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: Given the comments I would say this question is a duplicate of the standard https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. Would you agree? Also very relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I searched stackexchange but obviously with the wrong catchwords, that's why i opened a new question.