# Unable to create formatted bibliography or citation call-outs

Tags: biblatex, biber

after the encoding, citation call-outs do not appear as they should. They appears like this:

> I doubt that there is any useful information here (**Scha85**), **Scha85**.

the bibliography does not appear as well.

here the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{distib.bib}

%==================== Algorithm ===
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package last

\begin{document}

I doubt that there is any useful information here 
Scha85.\parencite{Scha85}, \textcite{Scha85}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

% here the is the bibliography. it is just a portion of 100 items of them

```
@book{Dori,
author={Dorigo, M. and Caro, G.D.},
title={The Ant Colony Optimization Meta-Heuristic},
year={1999},
editor={D. Corne, M. Dorigo, and F. Glover},
publisher={New Ideas in Optimiztion},
address={McGraw-Hill}}

@phdthesis{Horn97,
author={Horn, J.},
title={The Nature of Niching: Genetic Algorithms and the Evolution of Optimal, Cooperative Populations},
year={1997},
type={Doctoral dissertation},
school={University of Illinois, Illinois Genetic Algorithm Lab},
address={Urbana},
key={95001}}

@inproceedings{DAP,
    author = {Kalyanmoy Deb and Samir Agrawal and Amrit Pratap and T. Meyarivan},
    title = {A Fast Elitist Non-Dominated Sorting Genetic Algorithm for Multi-Objective Optimization: NSGA-II},
    booktitle = {Parallel Problem Solving from Nature VI Conference},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {849-858}}

@techreport{glass2012,
author={UN-Water GLASS},
title={The Challenge of Extending and Sustaining Services},
year={2012},
institution={World Health Organization}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you follow the ususal compiling chain: `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `biber mwe`, `pdflatex mwe.tex` twice? Make sure you called `biber` and not `bibtex`!

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to something more suitable for your question (then others can easily find it in the future)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your title to make it more informative and of adding the `biber` tag.

Comment: yes i followed every all steps, and thank you for editing

Comment: These bold citations keys mean that either biber didn't run at all or gave an error. Check the blg-file for clues.

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document (instead of BibTeX), so that a full compilation sequence at least consists of LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where 'LaTeX' is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for some background on Biber.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 can help you to set up your editor with Biber. If you ran Biber, you should get a `.blg` file (on Windows machines the `.blg` file may be classed as a 'performance monitor file', it is not, it is a normal text file you can open with your editor).

Comment: ... Open the `.blg` file and post its full contents here. We can't investigate your code any further, because we don't know the contents of your `distib.bib`.

Comment: I try doing that, but they continue to lay out the keyword in bold. so far there is not a .blg file

Comment: If there is no `.blg` file, you didn't run Biber. Do you compile your document from an editor or from the command line? Can you try to compile your document from the command line to exclude possible sources of error and interference?

Comment: The excerpt of your `.bib` file does not contain the entry `Scha85` from your document, so it doesn't really lend itself to testing. The only problem with your entries that I could spot is `editor={D. Corne, M. Dorigo, and F. Glover},`: Regardless of the desired output, all names in a name field must be separated with an `and`, the style will take care of the output formatting, so it should be `editor={D. Corne and M. Dorigo and F. Glover},`. In the example that was not a fatal error, but there are cases where similar problems can be fatal.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: well,, sorry for not copying the Schaffer (1985) article, it is part of my bibliography, and I run it in latex. I also changed bibtex.exe to biber.exe in console application on command mode

Comment: Till now no result showed up, and no .blg file

Comment: As I say: If there is no `.blg` you didn't run Biber. If you compile from the command line, you need to run `pdflatex document`, `biber document`, `pdflatex document`, `pdflatex document` (assuming your main `.tex` file is `document.tex` and you compile with `pdflatex`, you can replace "`pdflatex`" with your favourite LaTeX compiler). If you are using an editor you need to configure it for Biber and then instruct it to run Biber. How you do that depends on the editor. Some run Biber automatically or semi-automatically, with others you need to explicitly call Biber by clicking some buttons

Comment: thank you it works

Comment: @moewe, thank you. I configured my biblatex with biber , now every thing is ok , no crash