# How to refer inline to multiple authors using Bibtex?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

For my thesis I started to use LaTeX as a text editor. I am now in the process of figuring out basically everything. But the coding is not completely unknown to me. However, I get stuck on small point. I want to refer to articles that I used, by showing their surnames follwed by a comma and then the the year of publication.

Currently my code of the main file looks like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\beren\Documents\Master SCM\Thesis\Images} }
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=1mm, bindingoffset=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{My Name}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

My code in references.bib would look like this for example:

```
@book{NSP,
    author        = {A. Doe, W. Schoenmakers},
    title         = {North Sea Ports in Transition: Changing Tides},
    year          = {1998},
    chapter = {2 Port of Rotterdam: From Landlord to Mainport}
}
```

As you can see the book includes multiple authors, currently only Doe is showing up in the inline reference, but this should also be Schoenmakers. Could someone explain what I do wrong in the coding?

```
as well \parencite[33]{NSP}
```

[image]

I prefer to use APA style referencing. I know that a package exists for this as well, but I am using Bibtex which should also do the job.

One question adding to that for probably in the future, how would this work if I want to refer to the same source (consisting of multiple (3+) authors) again, but then using et al. instead?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: Note that you are not using a BibTeX-based approach to the bibliography, you are using `biblatex` with BibTeX as backend. This might look like nit-picking, but is actually a big difference. You may want to consider switching to Biber as backend, since BibTeX is designated a 'legacy backend' now and only supports a reduced feature set. It should also be noted that `style=authoryear,` does not give you APA style, it only gives you something that is superficially similar in the sense that both `authoryear` and APA are author-year styles. ...

Comment: ... If you want APA style, you can use `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,` but in that case you *must* use Biber as your backend (change `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Finally, if you want to cite only one chapter of *North Sea Ports in Transition: Changing Tides*, then the entry type `@incollection` would be more appropriate. If you want to cite the entire book, then `@collection` would be correct. My entries would look more or less like https://gist.github.com/moewew/9701d313152bb3c5cbc36bee13efab79

Comment: Thank you for your elaborative answer, @moewe. That sounds like a great idea and I tried to implement it. However my problem is that the bibliography is not showing up at all and that the inline references only refer to the name of the citation in the references.bib file. I changed that file to a 'Biber' file within Texworks.

I changed the following:
```
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Either you didn't run the whole sequence LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...) or the Biber run fails for some reason. Can you upload the `.blg` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. (The `.blg` file is a simple text file you can open with any text editor even though it may be recognised as "performance monitor file" by Windows).

Comment: Sure, I did it: https://gist.github.com/Bassieboy35/bfbcd56a28f34818b7cd8a0cd3754002

Comment: Are you running Biber on the `.bib` file? It should be run on the main `.tex` file. You need to run the sequence LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (e.g. assuming your `.tex` file is called `doc.tex` you run `pdflatex doc`, `biber doc`, `pdflatex doc`, `pdflatex doc` the name of the `.bib` file doesn't come in).

Comment: You are right about that, I ran the .bib file through Biber but changed it now as the way you said it. It works now, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` and not `,` as the separator for author names in the `bib`file. It should be `author = {A. Doe and W. Schoenmakers},` not `author = {A. Doe, W. Schoenmakers},`. With what you have `BiBTeX` understands that `A. Doe` is the family name and `W. Schoenmakers` the first name.