# Jabref Multiple Authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, jabref

I have 4 authors for one article but I get one name and initals for all the others:

```
@Article{everythingIPA,
  author       = {Federico Berruti \& Graeme Nixon\& Giambattista Taglioni\& Rob Whiteman},
  journal      = {McKinsey Digital},
  title        = {Intelligent process automation: The engine at the core of the next-generation operating model},
  year         = {2017},
  date         = {2017-03},
  journaltitle = {McKinsey Digital},
}
```

I've tried using `,` or `;` as separators and that way, I can get 2 names correct but not all 4.

Comment: You are almost there (and have almost tried anything). Names must be separated with `and`: `author = {Federico Berruti and Graeme Nixon and Giambattista Taglioni and Rob Whiteman},`. Commas are only used to separate bits of the same name (both `Sigfridsson, Emma` and `Emma Sigfridsson` mean the same). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: Strange, I saw another comment saying you should avoid using `and`, anyway it worked, thanks! If you write out the answer I can accept it.

Comment: Mhhh, no `and` is definitely the only correct way to separate two names in the `.bib` file. Maybe the comment was talking about something else. Since the question is basically answered by  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 can we close it as a duplicate instead of writing an answer saying the same as the accepted answer there?