# Misplaced alignment tab error

Tags: bibliographies, errors

Im getting this error, on a simple code, and i dont understand it.

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

it shows up on this line.

It says:

```
You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead."

\namepartgiven ...medelimb Schultz\bibnamedelimb &
                                                  \bibnamedelimb Nikolaj\bib...
l.254 \printbibliography[heading=none]

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

Comment: You need to separate authors with `and` in your `.bib`. That is, use `Schultz and Nikolaj`, not `Schultz & Nikolaj`.

Comment: I cant seem to find schultz or nikolaj in my .bib page.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with a `.bib` entry containing `Schultz` and `Nikolaj` (possibly in another order). Regardless of the desired output, you must use `and` to separate several names in the `.bib` file input: **`author = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},`** not \*`author= {Sigfridsson, Emma & Ryde, Ulf},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: I found it! thanks a lot!

Comment: The error is saying you that `&`, is not in a table (or a tabular-ĺike environments), where it is used as a cell separator. In any other places is wrong, and it should be typed  `\&` except as separator of authors in `.bib` files, that as commented it should be  *always* ` and  `  even if the final result must be "penultimate-author & last-author",  because that  should not be specified on the reference source but choosing the right  bibliographic style.