# Sort references (not authors) alphabetically

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I am new to LaTeX and am trying to sort my references alphabetically. As I mentioned in the title I want to sort the references, but not the order of the authors.

Here is the bibliography style that I have tried:

```latex
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

But none of these styles works for me, it sorts the authors as it's shown in the figure below. I want to keep the order that I have set.

[image: Author's names are sorted alphabetically]

Here is more explanation:

We assume that we have three references with three authors in each reference.

- Ref1's authors [ G, F and A ]
- Ref2's authors [ A, Z and E ]
- Ref3's authors [ C, B and F ]

I want a result like this:

- Reference 2 [ A, Z and E ]
- Reference 3 [ C, B and F ]
- Reference 1 [ G, F and A ]

Note that I don't use any file of bibliography, I just use:

```
\bibliography{bibli/my_refs} : to refer the location of my references.
\bibliographystyle{plain} : to specify the style of the bibliography.
```

Comment: The input `author = {I. Harichane, S.A. Makhlouf, G. Belalem},` is wrong. Multiple names *must* be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output in the bibliography. The correct input would be `author = {I. Harichane and S.A. Makhlouf and G. Belalem},`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. I know of no BibTeX style that would ever try to sort the names within a field (such as `author`). But `plain` should sort your references alphabetically by author names. `unsrt` will sort them by citation order. (I didn't check what `ieeetr` does.)

Comment: Thats true, when I substitute `,` by `and` it kept the desired custom order of the authors, thank you. But I still can't find the way to sort the references ( Vertically ) alphabetically...

Comment: As I said `plain` should sort references alphabetically by authors. If that does not work for you, you need to show us a full example document that reproduces what you are seeing with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). (We also need a few example `.bib` entries. They and the rest of the code should be posted as copyable code, **not** as images.)