# overleaf biber backend doesn't compile

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, overleaf

I've finished my document and now I'm working on a perfect bibliography...
I've used bibtex so far but it gives me some trouble as I need to change some stuff from English into German.

I think a way around that is to use the biber backend. This is working in an example document but not in my real document... the bibliography doesn't get printed out there....

some help here would be great as googeling hasn't helped me so far...the following example shows the problem.
I think that this issue is caused by the IPCC citation...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.6cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

 \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{bibgerm}
%\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

test something here \cite{IPCC-climareport}

\printbibliography

%\bibliographystyle{plaindin}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{plaindin.bst}
%\bibliography{literatur.bib}

\end{document}
```

this is the `literatur.bib` file

```
@article{IPCC-climareport,
title = " Summary for Policymakers. ",
journal = "In: Global Warming of 1.5°C. An IPCC Special Report on the impacts of global warming of 1.5°C above pre-industrial levels and related global greenhouse gas emission pathways, in the context of strengthening the global response to the threat of climate change, sustainable development, and  efforts  to  eradicate  poverty",
url = "\url{https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/sites/2/2019/05/SR15_SPM_version_report_LR.pdf}",
pages = "4",
author = "Masson-Delmotte,  V.,  P.  Zhai,  H.-O.  Pörtner,  D.  Roberts,  J.  Skea,  P.R.  Shukla,  A.  Pirani,  W.  Moufouma-Okia,  C.  Péan,  R.  Pidcock,  S.  Connors,  J.B.R.  Matthews,  Y.  Chen,  X.  Zhou,  M.I.  Gomis,  E. Lonnoy, T. Maycock, M. Tignor, and T. Waterfield (eds.)",
keywords = "special climate report"
}
```

Comment: @Community as error it says "empty bibliography"

Comment: if you are getting errors from an earlier bibtex run you may need to delete the generated files (Overleaf has a `clear cached files` menu option)  under `view logs` that will force it to do a clean latex biber latex latex run.

Comment: Instead of `\input{test1/firstPage}` and then telling us the content of `firstPage`, it would be a better example to just have that text at that point.  Do you still have the error in that case?  Also, make sure to highlight your code and click `{}` when editing, so that it still looks like code.

Comment: @Teepeemm changed! Sorry I havent thought about writing straight into main as I#M never doing this

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. Note that the `url` field should contain the raw URL, so there should be no `\url{...}` macro in that field. The type `@article` should only be used for articles that were published in a journal, this does not appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

If you run pdflatex then biber, biber reports

```
ERROR - Name "Masson-Delmotte, V., P. Zhai, H.-O. Pörtner, D. Roberts, J. Skea, P.R. Shukla, A. Pirani, W. Moufouma-Okia, C. Péan, R. Pidcock, S. Connors, J.B.R. Matthews, Y. Chen, X. Zhou, M.I. Gomis, E. Lonnoy, T. Maycock, M. Tignor,"
 has too many commas, skipping entry 'IPCC-climareport'
```

(you will find the biber log in the overleaf logs menu)

commas are for separating name parts like `Carlisle, David`  use `and` to separate authors.

Comment: using \and the document is now comipiling...
there's a massive empty space in between the authors now though..

is there any way to get the output as author1, author 2, ...

atm it is: author 1               author 2              ...


what I find interesting too is that using 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literatur.bib}

instead of biber could handle the commas...

Comment: @learnPyt it couldn't handle the commas it just treated it as a single author with a very weird surname

Comment: biblatex has 10000 options and styles to get various layouts of author names and titles. You are better to ask a new question about that (there are people on site a lot better at biblatex than me:-) @learnPyt

Comment: @learnPyt `and` not `\and`, sorry